# making some words bold in textbox winform

Tags: c#, winforms

Maybe some of you can help me with the following problem. I want some words bolded in a textbox(winforms).

I have a string _descripton variable containing some description text. For example:
“ this is a description of a \b car \b0………… ”. Im trying to replace the string format with richtextformat like:

```
string _makebold = _description.Replace("\b", @"{\rtf1\ansi \b").Replace("\b0", " \b0.}");
```

to get the following result: this is a description of a @"{\rtf1\ansi \b car\b0.}"……….
And finally setting the text property of the richtextbox1:

```
richTextBox1.Text = _makebold;
```

I cant get that specific word bolded in a richTextbox and textbox doenst work either.
can anyone help me with a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using the [`Rtf` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.rtf(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: yes, doesnt work. im getting :{"File format is not valid."}  error

Comment: In that case, I'd take a further look at this that's mentioned in the docs: _"For the RTF codes, see "rich text format (RTF) Specification, version 1.6" in the MSDN library at http://msdn.microsoft.com/library"_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Rtf` property of the rich text box control.

For example, the following text adds the text "This text is in **bold**." to an existing RichTextBox control.

See this [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287595%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) link.

```
richTextBox1.Rtf = @"{\rtf1\ansi This is in \b bold\b0.}";
```

Comment: this works with a single line of text. If you have something like this:
richTextBox1.Rtf = @"{\rtf1\ansi This is in \b bold\b0.} additional text";
the additional text wont show

Comment: richTextBox1.Rtf = @"{\rtf1\ansi " + _description + " .}";  seems the be working.